# Grouping products that are the same but have slightly different titles/attributes

Tags: database, performance, algorithm, search-engine

I am showcasing a large amount of products to my website.
I have to group similar products from different websites,
which I have already crawled to my DB.
So that when a product is searched, it also displays the same product from another website too.

I tried following methods

1. Grouping by product title

   Result - Failed because Sony Xperia Z, Sony Xperia Z( black ) are same product but different title, so can’t be in same group.So error rate is very high.
2. Grouping by Attributes:

   Products with similar attributes and value are placed in one group.
   But its very slow and error rate is also high.
   As different products from different companies might have same attributes.

Which is the best way to do this.
Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Do you say that you consider XperiaZ and XperiaZ(black) as the same products? Shouldn't it be an attribute?

Comment: @Fabinout: No that was grouping by title only. They will fall in different category if they are grouped by title name only.

Answer (score 0):

I woult try to use your Grouping by Title solution but modified with RegEx. Or just use methods like:

`title1.contains(title2)`

`title1.startsWith(title2)`

There can't be a 100% error free solution so i would add a link like this:
"Not your Product? Klick here" 
to remove the Product temporaly from this group and marks it as "not sure" so you can check it manually.

Comment: On modified with RegEx, can you give an example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the first letter and a dictionary and then use mysql fulltext search and order by relevance. The question isn't very clear. There is also the levensthein distance and the soundex() function.